# How do I match the line before and after a pattern match in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I am matching a pattern and getting the line of the match using `$.`

I need to print the line matching before the particular pattern and after the particular pattern, e.g.:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

After my pattern matches `line3`, I want to print `line2` and `line4`.

How can I do a pattern match in Perl? Can any one help me?

Thanks in advance

Senthil

Comment: what have you trie so far? And what if more line match? Or even two consequetive lines?

Answer (score 3):

You want what is normally called context.  The easiest way to get context is to maintain it yourself with a variable:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $old;
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    if ($line =~ /line3/) {
        print "$old$line", scalar <DATA>;
        last;
    }
    $old = $line;
}

__DATA__
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

If you need more than one line of context, it is better to use an array:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $context = shift || 3;
if ($context < 0) {
    $context = 0;
}

my @old;
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    if ($line =~ /line6/) {
        print @old, $line;
        for (1 .. $context) {
            print scalar <DATA>;
        }
        last;
    }
    push @old, $line;
    #remove a line if we have more than we need
    if (@old > $context) {
        shift @old;
    }
}

__DATA__
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
```

Answer (score 3):

With the entire file in a scalar, write your pattern so it captures the lines before and after `line3`. The [`/m` modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) is especially useful:

> Treat string as multiple lines. That is, change `^` and `$` from matching the start or end of the string to matching the start or end of any line anywhere within the string.

The patterns below use the `/x` modifier that lets us add whitespace to make them look like what they're matching.

For example:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my $pattern = qr/ ^(.+\n)
                  ^line3\n
                  ^(.+\n)
                /mx;

if ($data =~ /$pattern/) {
  print $1, $2;
}
else {
  print "no match\n";
}

__DATA__
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

Output:

```
line2
line4
```

Remember that `$` is an assertion: it doesn't consume any characters, so you have to match newline with a literal `\n` pattern.

Also note that the pattern above lacks generality. It works fine for a line somewhere in the middle, but it will fail if you change `line3` to `line1` or `line5`.

For the `line1` case, you could make the previous line optional with a `?` quantifier:

```
my $pattern = qr/ ^(.+\n)?
                  ^line1\n
                  ^(.+\n)
                /mx;
```

As expected, this produces output of

```
line2
```

But trying the same fix for the `line5` case

```
my $pattern = qr/ ^(.+\n)?
                  ^line5\n
                  ^(.+\n)?
                /mx;
```

gives

```
no match
```

This is because after the final newline in the file (the one following `line5`), `^` has nowhere to match, but changing the pattern to

```
my $pattern = qr/ ^(.+\n)?
                  ^line5\n
                  (^.+\n)?
                /mx;
```

outputs

```
line4
```

We might stop here, but the asymmetry in the pattern is unpleasing. Why did work for one case and not for the other? With `line1`, `^` matches the beginning of `$data` and then matches nothing for `(.+\n)?`.

**Remember:** patterns quantified with `?` or `*` *always* succeed because they're semantically the same as

- zero times or one time
- zero or more times

respectively, and *anything* can match zero times:

```
$ perl -le 'print scalar "abc" =~ /(?!)*/'
1
```

Although I can't think of a time I've ever seen it used this way, an `{m,n}` quantifier where *m* is zero, *e.g.*,

- {0,100}
- {0,}
- {0}

will always succeed because *m* is the minimum number of repetitions. The `{0}` quantifier is a pathological case included for completeness.

All that was to show we more or less got lucky with the `line1` case. `^` matched the very beginning, the `?`-quantified pattern matched nothing, and then the next `^` also matched the very beginning of `$data`.

Restoring symmetry makes a cleaner pattern:

```
my $pattern = qr/ (^.+\n)?
                  ^line5\n
                  (^.+\n)?
                /mx;
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize you asked for a Perl solution, but here is a Unix `grep` solution anyway:

```
grep -C 1 line3 file.txt
```

outputs:

```
line2
line3
line4
```

From the `grep` manpage:

> ```
>    -C NUM, --context=NUM
>     Print  NUM lines of output context.  Places a line containing --
>     between contiguous groups of matches.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Using unix command line power is great is such cases and perl embraces it.
try something like `grep -A 1` or `grep -B 1`
it will give you the line after/before

Comment: Oh, and although the solutions above will work, they are a hell of alot harder to code and are not needed in such a case